# Hide button "Create & Add Another" by condition in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

if I create a new resource by reference from the related resource

`new?viaResource=some-resource&viaResourceId=8&viaRelationship=another-sesource`

I want to hide the button "Create & Add Another".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Hy6.png

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1620#issuecomment-516384334

> this can be easily done using custom CSS:
>
> 1. Create `public/css/custom.css` with next lines:
>
>    ```
>    button[dusk='update-and-continue-editing-button'], button[dusk='create-and-add-another-button'] {
>        display: none;
>    }
>    ```
> 2. Install `custom.css` in `NovaServiceProvider.php`:
>
>    ```
>    public function boot()
>        {
>            parent::boot();
>            Nova::style('custom-fields-css', public_path('css/custom.css'));
>        }
>    ```